# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Biology's [third moderator election](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: theforestecologist] [image: Bryan Krause]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking WYSIWYG who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5587354624458752/0).

Comment: Welcome guys. I'm really happy to have you on the team. Well deserved.

Comment: Congrats guys!  Wishing you all the best!  *<Goes off to flag tons of stuff...>*

Comment: Congrats @BryanKrause and @theforestecologist!

Comment: Thanks, all! Glad to be aboard :). And thanks to the other candidates (TanMath, L.B. S Pr, and De Novo) for your dedication and willingness to run in this election. I know the community appreciates your continued involvement -- and we need as many folks as possible to help moderate this site! So your efforts are much appreciated!  I'm sure Bryan would echo me in saying I'm looking forward to this new role and hope we can serve the community well.

Comment: Congrats! Well done!

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Congrats guys. Good going and good luck!

Comment: Indeed, I'd echo everything @theforestecologist said. Thanks to everyone else who volunteered to step up and for your continued role as community moderators :)

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations to both new moderators, thanks for joining the mods.

I would also like to thank WYSIWIG for being a mod since this site graduated and also for his effort to achieve graduation. I hope you will still join us, despite of time restraints.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. Now I can unleash my close votes :D

Comment: @WYSIWYG Be careful. Or the new mods need to suspend you :-)